# (Excel) Is there a way to conditional format a cell from a range of cells based on the value of an another cell?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a cell with a text, which is the place of an another cell that I want to highlight. Lets say that it is the F6 cell, and in it, it says 'C6'. Is there a way to use conditional formatting to highlight the 'C6' cell ? Any other cell can be inputted into the F6 cell and the formatting will highlight it, if it is in the Data range.

[image: Sample picture]

Comment: Yes, with some code.  Your most complex issue is taking that string "C6" and making it an address reference on the sheet that VBA can understand.  You can control the cell and text color of a cell in VBA.  Just using conditional formatting form the ribbon?, I am not sure, but using VBA you can do this.

Comment: As long as each entry has a unique value you could use `=B4=indirect($F$6)`

Comment: @Lutz In my worksheet, there could be instances where the entries are duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the address of the current cell to the contents of F6, either:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4)=$F$6
```

or

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",B4),"$","")=$F$6
```

[image]

Comment: The second answer, with Substitute worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to write $C$6 you could use `CELL()`

Define conditional formating on `B4:D7` as `=CELL("address",B4)=$F$6`
`=CELL("address",B4)` will return the reference of that cell in the from of $COLUMN$ROW (e.g. `$C$6` for the cell `C6`) and that you can then compare.